# Incorrect (in my case) output of the path to the file. (PyQt6,speech_recognition)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyqt6

Below is the code. I am implementing an application with a GUI for transcribing audio files in the format .WAV to text.

```
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    def KonvertS(self):
        self.btnSpeech.text()
        wb_patch = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0] 
        print(wb_patch)
        file = sr.AudioFile(wb_patch)
        audio = r.record(file)
        recog = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        print(recog)
```

I have been struggling for a long time with the fact that the output of **wb_patch** would be correct in my case. I managed to achieve the desired result

`C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/Audio.wav`

As you can see, there is nothing superfluous, as is usually the case when selecting a file in PyQt. That format doesn't suit me However, now another problem has appeared - speech_rec does not accept such a path format. And no, I don't get an error, I only get the closing of the application.

`Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`

I'm not getting any text output from the audio. I have a feeling that the r.recognize handler simply does not see the file that I put into it

What could be my problem?

I tried looking for methods to convert web_path to similarity -
`r'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/Audio.wav`

Since usually, when specifying it directly to the handler, it worked, and at the output I got the desired text

However, now I'm making an application with a GUI, where the user will not have the opportunity to get into the code and rewrite it

Comment: what is the value of the `file` variable? Can you do `print(file)` so we can see its type and/or value?

Comment: Try to convert the slashes to double (escaped) backslashes: `sr.AudioFile(wb_patch.replace('/', '\\'))`. That shouldn't be required, but, better safe than sorry. Also, if you're using an IDE, did you try to run the program in a terminal or prompt?

Comment: `print(file)` gives the output 
`<speech_recognition.AudioFile object at 0x000002A950C77640>`

Comment: after adding this to the code - the slash just turned the other way without becoming a double
`C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/audio.wav`
`C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\audio.wav`

Comment: @takenao It *does*, the backslash is an escape character, when it's doubled it escapes itself, allowing proper backslash representation in strings, for instance while printing or **for file paths**. So, please don't point out the wrong aspect (which, by the way, is basic Python knowledge), instead answer the real question: does it work with that representation?

Comment: no, there is no output in this view anyway, the code stops, no more.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers in the comments above

It turned out to solve the problem as follows -

```
    def KonvertS(self):
        self.btnSpeech.text()
        AudioFile = (QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0])
        data, samplerate = soundfile.read(AudioFile)
        soundfile.write(AudioFile, data, samplerate, subtype='PCM_16')
        process = sr.AudioFile(AudioFile)
        with process as source:
            audio = r.record(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
        print(text)
```

It seems to me that the error about the mismatch of the file format simply did not appear, so the code stopped without output